# Can't find the error in my script

Tags: vbscript

Hey guys i have an problem with my vbs script. My script opens a text file reads it and removes some entrys. Somwhere in my script must be a error because the lastline of source file is written around 30 times in the destination file. I don't find the error in my code maybe someone of you sees it. Yes i know i shouldn't post large code parts.Here is my code:

```
separator = " "
x = 0

strRawPath = "C:\xampp_neu\xampp\htdocs\tc_backup\stasknoheader.txt"
strRawPathW = "C:\xampp_neu\xampp\htdocs\tc_backup\stask.txt"

Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fsw = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        ' 2 = ForWriting
        Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(strRawPath,1)
        Set w = fsw.OpenTextFile(strRawPathW,2)

            Do While f.AtEndOfStream <> True
                x = x+1
                'Anlegen des Arrays
                ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
                strLine = f.Readline
                'Speichern in Array
                myArray(x) = strLine

                'Loop so that lines that contains Microsoft or TaskName are not written
                 If InStr(strLine, "Microsoft") = 0 Then
                    If InStr(strLine, "TaskName") = 0 Then
                        If InStr(strLine, "Restart System") = 0 Then
                            If InStr(strLine, "Scheduler-HSM-mig-TC11TDrive") = 0 Then

                        strNewLine = strNewLine & strLine & vbCrLf
                        'Replace blank with " AM, "
                        strNewLine =(Replace(strLine," ",separator,1,2))
                        'Removes \ from TaskName
                        strNewLine =(Replace(strNewLine,"\","",1,1))
                        'WScript.Echo strNewLine
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If                  

                w.write strNewLine & VbCrLf
                'WScript.Echo strNewLine

            Loop 

        f.Close
        w.Close
```

Comment: so you mean to say this line  w.write strNewLine & VbCrLf  is written 30 times?

Comment: @AshReva only when the last line of the source file is written to the dest file it writes it 30 times all other lines are written once

Comment: thats because rest of the lines are inside the If condition and thats the only line which is outside your if condition. So that line will be executed till loop is running. Do you get any count or something from f.AtEndOfStream?

Comment: Your processing of `strNewLine` goes rogue, because in this statement `strNewLine =(Replace(strLine," ",separator,1,2))` you only replaces spaces in the last read strLine (in the last loop) with the separator. All other mutations on strNewLine are void. I think you wanted something like: `strNewLine =(Replace(strNewLine," ",separator,1,2))` (I replaced `newLine` by `strNewLine`).

Comment: Always, always start your scripts with [`Option Explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). I don't know if this will fix your problem, but it will help you at some time in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Although this wont solve your issue but would reduce your If conditions. You dont need 4 if condition. Just use And operator like below

```
If InStr(strLine, "Microsoft") = 0 And InStr(strLine, "TaskName") = 0 And InStr(strLine, "Restart System") = 0 AndA  InStr(strLine, "Scheduler-HSM-mig-TC11TDrive") = 0 Then


                    strNewLine = strNewLine & strLine & vbCrLf
                    'Replace blank with " AM, "
                    strNewLine =(Replace(strLine," ",separator,1,2))
                    'Removes \ from TaskName
                    strNewLine =(Replace(strNewLine,"\","",1,1))
                    'WScript.Echo strNewLine

End If
```

Comment: -1 for incorrect answer: Your `Or` suggestion contains not the correct logic, this should be `And`.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos oops i agree completely. Will change it now.